# Debugging registerForRemoteNotificationTypes more then once

Tags: iphone, push-notification

It's crazy, but in order to debug registerForRemoteNotificationTypes I'm resetting my iPhone every time!
In apple [TN2265](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html) they say:

> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by setting the system clock forward a day or more, turning the device off completely, then turning the device back on.

This doesn't work in iOS 5!

Anyone solved it?!

Comment: I think no one knows what to do with this...